# Perform HTTP-Authentification from PHP (Serverside)

Tags: php, .htaccess, http-authentication

I am trying have basic-HTTP-Authentification coupled with my own PHP/SQL Based authentification System, to Allow/Deny directory access via .htaccess.

Directory structure is like that:

```
 index.php
 data/
      file1.pdf
      file2.pdf
      .htaccess [Wich requires Username & Password for this directory!]
```

The user should authentificate in the php script, which triggers a fancy mechanic, so that now can access the files inside the data-folder - without performing the httpauthentification stuff as user.

I think this is a Job for a Javascript - but i could not figure out how.
The directory access is only granted to Admins of the site, so it would be no problem to transfer the password to the client - but not preferred!

I know that I can implement this stuff via mod_rewrite and a script, that just sends the pdf-Content and a MIME application/x-pdf header.

I would love to see an approach to the first solution.

I think it will work like that:

1. Authentificate via php/mysql
2. Authentificate the Client at apache
3. Tell the client authentification details

How do I implement this?

Comment: Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Still not sure if you are asking something or just saying things. Anyway, what you are talking about already exists for ages, it's built in to Apache. Google 'htaccess requires auth'. Good luck!

Comment: Yeah - I know that stuff, and that is exactly the technology I want to use - i dont want to see the username/password box on my clients! I want that PHP or JS authentificates me against the htaccess!

Comment: You can't. Apache's `.htaccess` based authentication mechanism WILL trigger the browser's built in authentication popup (username & password). However, the authentication details will be available for PHP later on. If you want to avoid the browser provided popup, you need to implement your own dialogue for username/password and its validation.